# Why is the purpose of capacitor CS?

Tags: capacitor

Solving the circuit below and as part of that I'm figuring out the purpose of these different capacitors.

- Coupling capacitors at the input and output to separate bias matters from the AC signal
- Emitter capacitor C<sub>E</sub> to bypass emitter resistance R<sub>E</sub> in order to boost AC gain

What is the purpose of capacitor C<sub>S</sub>? I can't seem to figure it out.

[image]

Comment: Where did you get the circuit? Didn't it come with any explanation?

Answer (score 5):

Capacitor Cs attenuates supply ripple from modulating base bias current and then getting amplified by gm since Re is bypassed by Ce for high AC gain.

Technically this improves the [PSRR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_supply_rejection_ratio).

Comment: So could it just be considered like a decoupling capacitor the base bias "rail"?

Comment: Vcc + ripple - RC LPF = Vbias.. exactly

Comment: Is R11 there for the Cs? I don't see why it would be there if Cs was not there since I see no reason why it should split the supply for RC and R12 otherwise. Actually, I'm not sure why you can't just have Cs without R11 either.

Comment: To filter 100 Hz by -40dB  say , X(Cs)/R11 = 1% thus to use smaller Cs you need bigger R11 at this low frequency cutoff of 1Hz. so if R11 =20k then Cs= ? For RC=0.16. If R=1 what is C? 0.16 Faraday